# SQLite with WPF Application deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

C# WPF Application with Sqlite not working after deployment.
It is working fine when I test the app in the debug folder. I am copying the database.DB file with MSIX Installer In the user's Application folder. But, when I install the Application with setup and try to run it from `C://Program Files/Publisher/Application/app.exe` it gives no output, no error. Maybe you find that question similar with some other questions like that but i tried their solutions as well but didn't work for me. I am using EF6.

**Connection String**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\tagit.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
InitializeComponent();
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",
         Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

**Database file path**
`C:\Users\darkcoder\AppData\Roaming\tagit.db`

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Can you provide logs, exceptions thrown?

Comment: I second that comment, it is not clear what the actual problem is. You can edit your post to add more information.

Comment: Are you using EF6?

Comment: yes i am using ef6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I finally found the solution.
The project wasn't working due to dependency of SQLite.Interop.dll So I added the file in MSIX Installer Manually and it worked!.

Comment: Simply right-click on the MSIX project you made in solution and click on the "Add > File".

Comment: "I am copying the database.DB file with MSIX Installer In the user's Application folder." - How do you do that?